# aerogear push notification not receiving in devices

Tags: android, notifications, push, aerogear

I was doing **POC** for Push notification from example given in [github](https://github.com/jboss-mobile/unified-push-helloworld) . I hosted Unified Push server in **OpenShift**. So registration and sending push notification from Unified Push server console are successful(status of message and registration count increased). But device is not receiving these notification.

Anyone having idea what might be wrong?

I am using Android Lollipop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you sent out messages, did you filter out users using "alias"? This is the most common issue from my experiences supporting app teams.